# compute multiple dataframes in parallel with spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to use the parallelize property of spark to compute multiple spark dataframes in parallel.

What i do : foreach id of an IDList (composed of more than 100 000 elements), i query df(id) from a database and execute algorithm on df.

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("scTest")
    val sparkContext = new SparkContext(sparkConf)

    val sparkSession = org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.builder
      .appName("sparkSessionTest")
      .getOrCreate

    val IDList = List("ID1",...,"ID100000")

    IDList.foreach(idString => {
      val df = executeQuery(idString,sparkContext)
      executeAlgorithm(df, sparkSession)    

    })
```

it works but this method execute the process on one ID after one.

How to parallelize the process to be more efficient ? One of the constraint is that i need sparkContext inside executeQuery and sparSession in executeAlgorithm, and they are not serializable. 
I run this on a yarn cluster.

Thank's in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is to execute the jobs in parallel then you can just use a parallel collecton:

`IDList.par.foreach`

Furthermore if you want to control the parallelism of how many jobs run at once, then you can assign your own `tasksupport` to the parallel list returned from `IDList.par`. Once the jobs are submitted in parallel then spark will use its scheduler to balance between them.